# Reformatting LaTeX code after excel2latex

Tags: tables, formatting, editors

I use `excel2latex` to generate tables from Excel.  The issue is that `excel2latex` generates really horribly formatted code with extra spaces, misaligned, etc.  Does anyone have another solution to creating tables from excel? Alternatively from R? It seems that typing the actual table out could be pretty cumbersome.  Another solution might be to have a piece of software that would format the code that `excel2latex` generates... does something like this exist?  I use notepad++ and TeXWorks to edit the code.

EDIT This is the error I get from running that script:

```
C:\Users\alchernyakov\Dropbox\beta_var\paper_sys_idio_vol\table_tex_files>perl indent.plx test.tex > formatted_test.tex
Bareword found where operator expected at indent.plx line 9, near "<title>latexindent"
    (Missing operator before latexindent?) syntax error at indent.plx line 5, near "html>"
Unrecognized character \xC2; marked by <-- HERE after at master <-- HERE near column 53 at indent.plx line 9.
```

Comment: try @cmhughes's `indent.plx` link: http://tex.blogoverflow.com/2012/08/a-perl-script-for-indenting-tex-files/

Comment: related [latex-code-sniffer-and-or-beautifier](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26102/latex-code-sniffer-and-or-beautifier) (thanks for the plug @HarishKumar :) )

Comment: The list: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49414/comprehensive-list-of-tools-that-simplify-the-generation-of-latex-tables

Comment: Why do you want to edit the code after exporting it from Excel2LaTeX?

Comment: because most of the time excel2latex generates a fairly poor table and manual editing is required

Comment: @HarishKumar: the file suggested doesn't work on windows with ActivePerl... i end up writing my papers on a windows machine.. any ideas what the problem is?

Comment: If the tables are simple I prefer to insert empty columns in Excel myself which are Then filled with ampersands manually.

Comment: @Alex: `doesn't work` is not good enough to get help? Please give some more details. It works for me. Please see my long comment as answer. Pl. try that way. I also used `active perl`. Please provide one of your tables so that we can try on that also.

Comment: @Alex: I just wonder -- what do you want to edit manually? Which particular features a table can have are missing?

Comment: @HarishKumar: posted above what the error is

Comment: @cmhughes: Will you please have a look at this error? Please.

Comment: @HarishKumar your answer is great (+1) :) can't think of a better way to describe the process... perhaps you could link to Paulo's great answer here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37610/how-to-make-the-rmligs-script-available-globally-on-windows

Comment: @Alex: You **must not** download directly https://github.com/cmhughes/latexindent.plx ! Go on it, then click on “indent.plx” and _then_ download by clicking on the “Raw” button! Your error message comes from the HTML file you actually downloaded.

Comment: @cmhughes Thank you. I think speravir has nailed the error. :-)

Comment: wow, this was stupid of me. sorry about that guys.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not an exact answer but a reply to one of the comments above. (Can't have formatted code in comment)

> the file suggested doesn't work on windows with ActivePerl... i end up
>   writing my papers on a windows machine.. any ideas what the problem
>   is?

First, we have to install `perl` -- either strawberry or active and the perl should be included in system path (important). For some more details pl refer to [this question and answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37610/how-to-make-the-rmligs-script-available-globally-on-windows)

Then if your `.tex` file is in a folder `c:\myfolder\myfile.tex` (say), open command prompt and navigate to this folder typing

```
cd    cd myfolder
```

If you are on a different drive, other than `C:` as suggested by **Speravir** you can also type (instead of above lines)

```
cd /d c:\myfolder
```

to reach `myfolder`.

Ensure that the file `indent.plx` is also in the same folder (or include its path to the system variable). Now type

```
perl indent.plx myfile.tex > myfile-formatted.tex
```

and press `Enter`.

This will generate a new file called `myfile-formatted.tex` (which is formatted) in the same folder. A little example:

**Before formatting:**

```
\documentclass{article}


\begin{document}
  % Table generated by Excel2LaTeX from sheet 'Sheet1'
\begin{tabular}{rrr}

         1 &    1000000 &       This \\

         2 &        200 &       That \\

         3 &     300000 &       Here \\

         4 &     500000 &    My name \\

         5 &      20000 & Is it so? Then OK \\

         6 &         10 & This works. \\

\end{tabular}

   % Table generated by Excel2LaTeX from sheet 'Sheet1' and misaligned by me
\begin{tabular}{rrr}

1      &    1000000             &       This \\

2  &        200    &       That \\

  3 &300000 & Here \\

 4              &     500000                                 &    My name \\

  5 &      20000             & Is it so? Then OK \\

            6 &         10     & This works. \\

\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

**After formatting:**

```
\documentclass{article}


\begin{document}
% Table generated by Excel2LaTeX from sheet 'Sheet1'
\begin{tabular}{rrr}

    1 & 1000000 & This              \\

    2 & 200     & That              \\

    3 & 300000  & Here              \\

    4 & 500000  & My name           \\

    5 & 20000   & Is it so? Then OK \\

    6 & 10      & This works.       \\

\end{tabular}

% Table generated by Excel2LaTeX from sheet 'Sheet1' and misaligned by me
\begin{tabular}{rrr}

    1 & 1000000 & This              \\

    2 & 200     & That              \\

    3 & 300000  & Here              \\

    4 & 500000  & My name           \\

    5 & 20000   & Is it so? Then OK \\

    6 & 10      & This works.       \\

\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

**Note:**

As noted by @speravir:

> You must not download directly https://github.com/cmhughes/latexindent.plx !
>   Go on it, then click on “indent.plx” and then download by clicking on
>   the “Raw” button! Your error message comes from the HTML file you
>   actually downloaded.

Comment: Harish Making one line from two: Replace `cd\ `<linebreak>`cd c:\myfolder` with `cd /d c:\myfolder` (in one line, as I said). “My” version works also, if one is one a different drive first, “your” version not.

Comment: But you can use “my” version always, also on the same drive. :-)

Comment: @Speravir: You are right. In fact I hate the command prompt. Don't tell anybody `;-)`

Comment: Oh, I will try. ;-)