# How to update MiKTeX 2.8 to 2.9 in WinEdt?

Tags: installing, miktex, winedt

I am trying to update MiKTeX from 2.8 to 2.9 in WinEdt. I downloaded the MiKTeX 2.9 and installed in `C:/program files/Miktex 2.9`. And then configure the MiKTeX in WinEdt by ＂Tex->Miktex-> Miktex options->roots＂, However, after restarting the winEdit, the MiKTeX Version is still 2.8. May someone help me?

Comment: As far as I recall the recommended procedure for moving from 2.8 to 2.9 was to first completely uninstalling 2.8 and then running  afresh install of 2.9. My suspicion is that the 2.8 env. variables occur before the 2.9 making 2.8 the "default". This has nothing to do with WinEdt so the best way forsward is to remove MiKTeX 2.8 and2.9 altogether and then install a fresh version of 2.9.

Comment: @PeterJansson: No it is not necessary to do a complete uninstall. But one should check the environment variables.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer there is another new problem, pls refer to http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/97985/the-required-file-tex-latex-standalone-standalone-cls-is-missing-after-installin, thanks

Comment: This link should help: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/89764

Answer (score -1):

I have solved it just rename the original MikTex 2.8 folder so that Winedt can not find it. Therefore, it uses the MikTex 2.9.

Comment: I’m sure, this is not a real solution, but a (bad!) workaround. I do not know, how WinEdt usually finds the executables, but it seems to me it can search the system path. So you should do, waht Ulrike already suggested: Check the environment variable `PATH` and if needed remove the path to MiKTeX 2.8 from it. At first put this in the command prompt on your system: `echo %path%`.