# The required file tex/latex/standalone/standalone.cls is missing after installing MikTex 2.9?

Tags: installing, miktex, updating

After installing the MikTex 2.9, Run the code in WinEdt, it always gives warning that The required file tex/latex/standalone/standalone.cls is missing, can someone help me how to fix the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can active 'Install Packages on the fly' option in MikTeX Settings or use MikTeX Package Manager to download packages.

Comment: Thanks, however when I actived install packages on the fly option, and run the code again, still some problem said "File tikz.sty not found".

Comment: @sweetyBaby: What is your winedt version?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer 6.0

Comment: Then it is possible that winedt is blocking the on-the-fly installation. Compile once in another editor (e.g. texworks which comes with miktex) or on the command line. Or install the missing packages with the package manager.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer thanks, I tried to install the missing packages with the package manager. The problem is solved, however, there is new problem says "tex\latex\pgf\frontendlayer\tikz.sty is missing", when I tried to solve it use the same method, the manager reported an error says "Windows API error 87: The parameter is incorrect." What's the problem? Thanks!

Comment: @sweetyBaby I've seen this error when trying to update or install some package and latex/pdflatex/... is still running on the background.

Comment: @Ignasi thanks, I tried to install the missing packages with the package manager. The problem is solved, however, there is new problem says "tex\latex\pgf\frontendlayer\tikz.sty is missing", when I tried to solve it use the same method, the manager reported an error says "Windows API error 87: The parameter is incorrect." What's the problem? Thanks!

Comment: @sweetyBaby: Read [miktex-2-8-update-error-windows-api-error-87](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18144/miktex-2-8-update-error-windows-api-error-87?rq=1)