# WinEdt can not recognize MiKTeX after setting the root

Tags: installing, miktex, winedt

I tried to update MiKTeX from version 2.8 to version 2.9. Then I installed the version 2.9 in `C:/program files/Miktex 2.9` and then configure the MiKTeX in WinEdt by ＂`Tex->Miktex-> Miktex options->roots`". However, after restarting the WinEdt, the MiKTeX can not use, the buttons of the MiKTeX  are disabled. Can someone help me?

Comment: The menu you mention leads to miktex options (and I have no idea what you did there) and has nothing to do with configuring winedt (which normally isn't necessary at all). Check in `options->execution modes` the diagnosis, path and texsystem-Tab.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer thanks, sorry, which "options" tab do you mean?

Comment: I would suggest that you simply check all options menu of all perhaps relevant applications for a submenu `execution modes`. I don't think that is asking to much of you.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer yes, I have checked it and set "Tex root" to the Miktex path under "tex" tab, however, when I choose the auto detect  , the Tex root changes. But If I don't choose the auto detect button, the buttons still are disabled.

Comment: I’m quite sure, that this is related to your older question [How to update MiKTeX 2.8 to 2.9 in WinEdt?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/97977/how-to-update-miktex-2-8-to-2-9-in-winedt).

Comment: @Speravir Yes, however, I solve the problem in my laptop, however, when I tried the same solution in my desktop, the other problem occurred like I described in this problem. Thanks.